# Twitter Search API multiple hash tags or users

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-search

I am trying to query the Twitter Search API for either a user, several users, a hashtag, several hashtags, or any combo of them. I am struggling with the syntax.

Multiple users (WORKS)

```
?q=from:user1 OR from:user2 OR from user3
```

Single hashtag (WORKS)

```
?q=with:#hashtag
```

Combo (BROKEN)

```
?q=from:user1 OR from:user2 OR with:#hash1 OR with:hash2
//returns most recent tweets and ignores my query altogether. No error
```

I do not want to query a specific hashtag from a specific user. I want either/or results. If I use the following syntax, it works, but it also searches the contents of the tweet, as opposed to just the hashtag, which is not as nice.

Contains search (WORKS)

```
?q=from:user1 OR hashtag1 OR hashtag2
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for or no? I have also tried the following

(BROKEN)

```
?q=from:user1 OR from:user2 OR with:hash1 OR hash2 OR hash3
```

Hope this make sense. I can clarify further if needed. (Note: I am using since_id and max_id in my actual environment, as well as rpp, but for the ease of this question, I left them out of my examples.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer was written in 2013. The API it uses has since been retired. It is kept for historical interest only. For Twitter API authenticated requests are now required now.

---

During same research i found to search with multiple hashtags in API V1.1. you can do like

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=#hashtag1+OR+#hashtag2

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=#hashtag1+AND+#hashtag2

AND/OR will be caps and not forgot to values URL encode. for more detail you can look here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: As authenticated requests are now required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097357/twitter-search-by-hashtag-example-api-v1-1

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use this type for hashtags or 2 simple words.

## haiku #poetry  :   %23haiku+%23poetry

“happy hour” :) :   %22happy%20hour%22%20%3A%29

can verify the information [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators.html).