# Live Web Feed + Masonry 'Wall' with CMS

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter

Oke so for a project I need to make this:

A wall like website. Kind of like Metro UI with Masonry. I want to make the blocks to hold text, images and tweets (live tweets). These texts and images are going to be submitted trough a CMS.

Here is the tricky part, I don't want to refresh to page to show the added content or new tweets. I was thinking AJAX + PHP/MySQL would solve this problem + Masonry jQuery.

In short, the idea behind it:
Wall with blocks that change after a set amount of time
If a new post is added this will automatically get in the rotation of random blocks
People who tweet with #hashtag will also automatically get in the rotation of random blocks
And this all without having to refresh.

I was wondering if you guys had any ideas for this on how to make it and with what technology. So I figured that I should use PHP, MySQL, AJAX, Masonry, jQuery and of course a working Twitter API.

Demo's or similar things regarding this 'wall' is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, some pointers to get you started:

You are going to want to call a function a regular time intervals I'm guessing, so you might want to look at the timeout function:
http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/

Then you'll want to use AJAX to get some data from a PHP file - optionally shown here with a parameter to specify you only want tweets with hashtag #cheese:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "a_php_file_that_returns_some_data.php",
  data: { hastag: "cheese"}
})
  success: function (dataFeed) {
                // do something
            }
);
```

OK, I said AJAX, but actually you don't want the X (XML) - it is easier to format your feed as JSON - for which you might find json_encode useful: https://www.php.net/json_encode

The PHP file will contain a function that gets data from twitter. You'll need to create an app on twitter which involves signing up for a free dev account: https://dev.twitter.com/

The app will have an API key - codes you send to twitter to unlock the data you want. The API changes from time-to-time so you'll need to look up the latest version, but here's something to start you off.
[Twitter search by hashtag example API v1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097357/twitter-search-by-hashtag-example-api-v-1-1)

Once you've got the json feed it's time to add the items to masonry, I'm not expert so refer to the docs for more, but here's the add items method:

```
msnry.addItems( elements )
// or with jQuery
$container.masonry( 'addItems', elements )
```